# Deleting firebase data from a web application

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to delete data from Firebase from within the application. I currently can add, amend and delete data directly from the console which updates in the application using the child_added, child_changed and child_removed.

Also, I can add data to Firebase using .push which also reflects the changes with the application.

However, I cannot find anything within the documentation to suggest how to remove data from Firebase through the application - Something like a bin icon next to each Firebase object which when clicked will remove that piece of data from the Firebase database and update within the application.

Is this possible? I'm going round in circles and still can't crack it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `JS` please use this code:

```
ref = new Firebase("myfirebase.com")
ref.remove();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I have the same question that I asked Faizy -
 How would I add this to my JS? Would it be a click event? My issue is that the child added function contains: document.createElement('li'); So until the page is running the li element does not exist so how would I create an on click event something not in my HTML?

Comment: You cannot create an on click event on something that is not in your HTML. You only can create on an item that exists. The flow is as follows, `display the items` -> ` create an on click event` -> `remove the child` as mentioned above.

Comment: So the document.createElement('li') is not the correct way of doing things?

Comment: Please take a look at this [tutorial](http://thejackalofjavascript.com/getting-started-with-firebase/).

Comment: Looks like a detailed tutorial - i'll give it a go! Thank you Alex

Comment: Works nicely - Going to try and get it so along side each piece of data there is a checkbox and you can delete any data which has been selected. Thats the plan anyway

Comment: Happy to hear that works. If you think that my answer helped you, consider accepting it . Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in two ways.

```
firebase.database().ref(CHILD_TO_DELETE).remove();
```

or

```
firebase.database().ref(CHILD_TO_DELETE).set(null);
```

> Something like a bin icon next to each Firebase object which when clicked will remove that piece of data from the Firebase database and update within the application.

The answer to this part is it can be inside a click event function of maybe a delete button.

Comment: Thank you Anand. This is a great answer works for me well so thank you. Do you know if theres any way that I can have, for example, tick boxes either side of every firebase object and once the user has checked them - They click a bin icon - and it removes all the checked items?

Comment: Your child will have some push IDs, so when checking the box collect the IDs and when you click bin button, make a new object _updates_ with children as :- `'<pushID>': null` Then execute `firebase.database().ref(PARENT_OF_YOUR_DATA).update(updates);`

Answer (score 0):

```
ref.child(key).remove();
```

In JS you could do it like shown above. Keep in mind, it´s asynchronus.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How would I add this to my JS? Would it be a click event? My issue is that the child added function contains: document.createElement('li'); So until the page is running the li element does not exist so how would I create an on click event something not in my HTML?